# Problem in multiple loops only one result is true

Tags: php, loops, google-custom-search

I am having problem in loops and conditions. I am trying to check if link is available in results from google custom search API. but only get last result true. Dont know why.

```
       foreach($array as $qqq => $kkk ){
            $found = "No";
            $kkk_en = urlencode($kkk);
            $page_rank = "" ;
            for ($page = 1;$page <= $pages && $found == "No";$page++){
                $apiurl = sprintf('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=%s&cx=%s&key=%s&hl=%s&gl=%s&start=%d',$kkk_en,$GOOGLE_CSE_CX,$GOOGLE_API_KEY,$hl,$gl,($page-1)*10+1);
                $json = file_get_contents($apiurl);
                $obj = json_decode($json);
                foreach ($obj->items as $idx=>$item) {
                    if (strpos($item->link, $domain) ){
                        $found = "Yes";
                        $page_rank = ($idx + ($page-1)*10);
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($found == "No"){
                $toolResult .= "<tr>
                <td>".$kkk."</td>
                <td>".$domain."</td>
                <td>Not in top 100</td>
                <td>".$hl." / ".$gl."</td></tr>";
            }
            else{
                $toolResult .= "<tr>
                <td>".$kkk."</td>
                <td>".$domain."</td>
                <td>".$page_rank."</td>
                <td>".$hl." / ".$gl."</td></tr>";
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are overwriting the same variable over and over in your foreach. Store the results in array, or move the if found = no/yes, into the foreach loop. Try to rewrite your code as well so you don't have double code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it with setting a global variable outside the loop..